# Error compiling VBA app after Office 2007 was installed

Tags: vba, office-2007

Ever since we installed Office 2007, our VBA app's code stopped working.  When I debug, I get a compile error and `.Edit` is highlighted.  I replaced the `.Edit` with `.Update` and I don't get any debug errors, but when I run the code I get a type mismatch error code.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Command290_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command290_Click
'This routine imports the latest Changepoint CSV file into the ChangepointCSV table.
'SR: valid routine

    Dim FullFileName As String      'full file path & name
    Dim myDB As Database
    Dim rstAsOfDate As Recordset
    Dim rstCumulativeResources As Recordset
    Dim strOldDate As String
    Dim tableExists As Integer
    Dim strExistingCSVTable As String
    Dim transferSuccessful As String
    Dim deleteBackup As Boolean

'set default values
    Set myDB = CurrentDb
    strExistingCSVTable = "ChangepointCSV"

'form maintenance to restrict user options
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmMain", acSaveNo
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmImportingCPData"

'get name of the existing CSV file
    'MsgBox ("before RS set")
    Set rstAsOfDate = myDB.OpenRecordset("tblChangepointFileName")
    'MsgBox ("after RS set")

    With rstAsOfDate
        'MsgBox ("inWITH")
       .Edit
        'Store original data.
        strOldDate = !CurrentFileName
    End With

    rstAsOfDate.Close

'get name of file to be imported
    FullFileName = GetFile()
    'MsgBox ("DEBUG  FullFileName = " + FullFileName)

    'FullFileName = "C:Documents and Settings ext.xlsx"

'compare existing to latest
    If strOldDate = FullFileName Then
        MsgBox "The RI currently contains the latest Changepoint data extract."
        deleteBackup = False
        GoTo RestoreForms
    End If

'if Changepoint CSV table exists then back it up in case of an error
    tableExists = ObjectExists_20%("Tables", strExistingCSVTable)

    If tableExists = -1 Then
        DoCmd.CopyObject , "ChangepointCSV-backup", acTable, strExistingCSVTable
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, strExistingCSVTable
    End If

'transfer the latest CSV file
    transferSuccessful = TransferSpreadsheetFile(strExistingCSVTable, FullFileName)
    'MsgBox ("DEBUG:  Transfer Successful:  " + transferSuccessful)

'if the lastest CSV file was NOT imported, restore the backup CSV and exit,
'else continue processesing.

    If transferSuccessful = 0 Then
        DoCmd.CopyObject , strExistingCSVTable, acTable, "ChangepointCSV-backup"
        MsgBox "The Changepoint data could not be refreshed at this time.  Please try again later."
        deleteBackup = True
        GoTo RestoreForms:
    Else
        'MsgBox ("before RS set")
        Set rstAsOfDate = myDB.OpenRecordset("tblChangepointFileName")
        'MsgBox ("after RS set")

        'Update Filename
            With rstAsOfDate
                'MsgBox ("inWITH")
                .Edit
                'Store original data
                !CurrentFileName = FullFileName
                .Update
            End With

        rstAsOfDate.Close
        'MsgBox ("RS closed")

        Set rstCumulativeResources = myDB.OpenRecordset("tbl_CumulativeResources")
        Do While Not rstCumulativeResources.EOF
            rstCumulativeResources.Delete
            rstCumulativeResources.MoveNext
        Loop

        rstCumulativeResources.Close

        DoCmd.RunMacro "mcrFTEAnalysis"
        deleteBackup = True
        GoTo RestoreForms

    End If

'restores main form and cleans up backup file
RestoreForms:
    If deleteBackup = True Then
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "ChangepointCSV-backup"
    End If

    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmImportingCPData", acSaveNo
    'MsgBox ("DEBUG:  import form closed")
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMain", acNormal

Exit_Command290_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command290_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command290_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: There are two different `.Edit` parts in that code. Which one is being flagged as the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess would be a problem with references. Are you using DAO or ADO for your data access? After checking your references try changing the DIM lines to DAO.Database etc if using DAO and ADODB.Database if using ADO.

Because both DAO and ADO contain a .Database object VBA can sometimes get confused as to which one you mean and the default changes from version to version from memory